# Simplifying multiple nested MYSQL select queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a hard time getting my head around nesting these SELECTs in order to use only one query to extract the data I need!

I need to find and return a row in the composition table that is has the latest date that is earlier than the the load date in the loads table.

This works but I should be able to do it in one query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM loads JOIN generators ON gen_key =gen_id ";
$sql.=" WHERE field_id= ".$fieldcode;
$sql.=" ORDER BY load_date DESC,load_time DESC ";
$result=mysqli_query($db_connection,$sql); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM composition WHERE comp_date <=   '".$row[load_date]."'  AND gen_id =".$row[gen_id]." ORDER BY comp_date ASC) as T1 ORDER BY comp_date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result2=mysqli_query($db_connection,$sql2); 
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// Output $row[] and $row2[] data
}
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Databse calls inside a loop are generally not a good idea. You should be able to do a join and achieve the result you want

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to minimize your queries from PHP to SQL you could use Stored Procedures.
Basically they are fast to wrap your head around. If you follow this quick tutorial on the topic you would be going in no time (I just did):
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

In this case you would end up with only having to call your one procedure once with one or more parameters from PHP to SQL - hence minimizing your queries drastically.

For example you would wrap the above SQL calls (more or less as they stand in your code) in a Stored Procedure, say `$sql = "call getGenerators(".$gen_id.");";` and the result would be whatever you selected in the stored procedure to be returned.

Stored Procedures are great at fetching data like in your case but less great at doing hard logics (which this is not).

Hope it helps.